# Need IntPtr for a Form (VB.Net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, handle, intptr

I need the intPtr for a form.  Control.FromHandle(control) gives me the control from a handle, but I need the opposite--get the handle from a control.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Dim handle As IntPtr = someControl.Handle
```

Note: This will only work after the Handle for the control is created.  There is a window of time in between when you create a control and when it is rendered to some degree where this *may* return IntPtr.Zero

Answer (score 1):

> Note: This will only work after the Handle for the control is created. There is a window of time in between when you create a control and when it is rendered to some degree where this may return IntPtr.Zero

I have to disagree with JaredPar on this : the get accessor of the Handle property calls CreateHandle if the handle is not yet created (you can check with Reflector). It's important to be aware of that because in some cases it could have unexpected consequences

Comment: Check the method in reflector.  There are cases where it simply will not create a handle.  It is not guaranteed to happen but can happen under certain configuration.

Comment: I must confess I had not analyzed the code of the CreateHandle method... now that I did, I find it a little confusing, and I'm not sure it always creates the handle. So maybe you're right eventually ;)

Comment: @Thomas, there is a far out corner case where the underlying state prevents handle creation. I only know it exists because I've hit it before because I assumed Handle will be valid before being disposed.  Been ~2 years so I can't remember the details (only the pain :) ).